# JSON response using HTTPPARTy always returns 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am sending a request to my rails API through HttpParty object :

```
 HTTParty.get(task_list_url(@hotel_id),
        :headers => { 'X-User-Email' => @user_email, 'X-User-Token'=> @user_token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
      )
```

I store this object in @response variable

The method on the API looks something like that

```
  def index
    @tasks = policy_scope(Task).where(hotel: @hotel)
    if current_user.created_account == @hotel.account || current_user.hotels.include?(@hotel)
      render json: {tasks: @tasks, hotel: @hotel}
    else
      render json: {
         :status => :unauthorized,
         :message => "unauthorized"
      }
    end
  end
```

The problem is in the else case the @response returned looks like that :

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7fbb0a580198 parsed_response={"status"=>"unauthorized", "message"=>"unauthorized"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "access-control-allow-methods"=>["POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"], "access-control-allow-headers"=>["Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token"], "access-control-max-age"=>["1728000"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"], "etag"=>["W/\"2cd59ce00f09c29553693183e9a04a4d\""], "cache-control"=>["max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"], "x-request-id"=>["5acc353c-48aa-410d-a4bc-888c653cae02"], "x-runtime"=>["0.459027"], "vary"=>["Origin"], "connection"=>["close"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"]}>
```

the relevant information is not in @response as you can see but in `parsed_response`. This creates a problem in my client app because I am checking @response which returns OK 200 whereas the correct return should be UNAUTHORIZED 401.

How can I put my correct json response in the @response object or if it is not possible how can do checks on parsed_response inside the HTTParty object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little correction of controller should do the thing.

Instead of:

```
render json: {
     :status => :unauthorized,
     :message => "unauthorized"
  }
```

Use this:

```
render json: { message: "unauthorized" }, status: :unauthorized
```